# Cannot launch every office 2007 product

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I have not been able to launch any office 2007 product(with comprehensive patches) since last Friday. Each office product shows different behavior but none of them work. When I use **Word** it will generate a alert box without any content inside.

And launch **Excel** -> shows something like "Missing the file XLLEX.DLL"
launch **Powerpoint** -> No reaction. 
**Visio(2003)**- Shows OS cannot configure it.
**Access** -> The install package cannot be opened.

So I tried to uninstall OFFICE 2007 and re-installed it again (from FTP HDD). But still the same. Then I tried MS "fix it: 50154" [**[link to the file decription](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971179)**] to completely remove the product. I also used the tool to remove its registry, and deleted the Normal.dot file located at **C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates**. Then, re-install again but nothing changed, neither OFFICE 2007 nor OFFICE 2003.

Does anyone have other ideas? I appreciate with your helps.

---

**Update**

Thanks for the replies. 
Sorry now I am using Japanese Windows system so I did not give full texts. Now texts are translated as below:

Running **Excel** will produce the text "lexicon（XLLEX.DLL）が見つからないか、または壊れています。", and its English version would be "a lexicon (XLLEX.dll) is missing or damaged".

Running **Access** and **Publisher** will produce "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.".

Running **Word** shows an alert message box without any contents:

[image]

Running **Outlook** will produce "Cannot start Microsoft Office Outlook. Cannot
initialize Microsoft Office shared utilities. Restart your computer or
reinstall Microsoft Office Outlook".

Running **Visio(2003)** will produce "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application".

Running **Powerpoint** and **Infopath** will have no reaction.

All office products' version are 2007(Word, Excel, Access, Powerpoint, Publisher, Infopath, Outlook), except Visio's is 2003. All of them are valid from the FTP server in my company. I did not buy them. All the patches are installed.

My laptop is HP ProBook 6550b, containing i5 CPU M560 @2.67Ghz, with 2 GB memory, Intel HD graphics and 250GB Hitachi HDD. OS is **Windows XP SP3**.

Comment: We need valid error messages, not "something like". Screen captures will be especially helpful, as well as the exact version and edition of Windows you're running, and possibly a hardware spec (CPU, RAM, HDD, etc.)

Comment: Many thanks for replies above. I have updated the details so please check them if they are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

I found the problem was derived from the possible damage in **user profile data**. Some solutions said the only way is to create a brand new account then the office soft can be launched. But currently I could not create an new account for myself so I tried to delete the following registry info:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-2334637194-694738329-1336345497-20725\Components\858132C493B23D11E8D0000CF486730D**

It might be the root of the problem after I googled it. Then I restarted my laptop. All products worked!

Please let me know if the solution is not comprehensive enough.

Comment: I was stuck with this problem for 2 days. Now it's solved, Thanks to you. It did the trick !!